# How to rename subfolders which contain same name in python

Tags: python, for-loop, operating-system, rename

I am trying to rename subfolders which start from `61440` to `122800` with odd order (1,3,5,...), but when reaches to same old name raised with error :

```
 WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists:
'Input_Intact/77120' -> 'Input_Intact/77121'
```

You can see the code below:

```
import os

for dirname in os.listdir("."):
       if os.path.isdir(dirname):
        for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(dirname)):
            j=i+1
            os.rename(dirname + "/" + filename, dirname + "/" + str(i+j))
```

Comment: Note that `os.listdir()` does *not* return the directory entries in any particular order. That is, you shouldn’t assume that they’re sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing mass-renaming of files like that, it can happen that the new name of a file is the same as the old name of another file. That will cause the error message you’re seeing (“file already exists”).

There are basically two ways to work around that.  The first is to rename the files in two steps: First, give all of them a temporary name (like appending `.tmp`, for example), so there cannot be collisions with existing files. Then, perform a second pass of renaming the files to remove that suffix.

The second way is to create a temporary subdirectory and move the files there while renaming. When done, move the files back to the original directory and remove the temporary subdirectory.